# Spring with Thymeleaf view integration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Starting out with Spring MVC and Thymeleaf for a project - But I am facing the issue of loading the index page -

My Controller is as follows -

```
@Controller

public class HomeController {

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
        public ModelAndView index(){
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("index");
            mav.addObject("user", new UserCredential());
            return mav;
        }
```

and my servlet.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="web.controller" />

    <!-- Enabling Spring MVC configuration through annotations -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!--  Mapping Static Resources -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.html"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

My file structure is --

```
WebContent
 -- WEB_INF
    -- views
      -- index.html
```

However I get the following exception -

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index1' in servlet with name` 'springMVC'

Am I placing the file in the wrong place or missing something in my controller?

Answer (score 6):

Solved it, I had to return the view name with the extension since I was telling my viewResolver to only resolve to names ending in .html ..
This thread pointed me to the answer http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Issue-with-my-Thymeleaf-Spring-configuration-td4024996.html