# I can't find answer that Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, servlets

I started study Spring MVC and tomcat just.

I want to display html page by Spring and ThymeLeaf VewTemplate Engine.

But It doesn't work.

below my configure File and Controller.

**web.xml File**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>EncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**/webapp/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet-serlvet.xml**

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.everblog.controller" />

<!-- ViewResolver be configured by thymeleaf -->
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="viewNames" value="*.html" />
</bean>
```

And Controller

```
@Controller
public class PostItemController {

   @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String helloWorld() {
      System.out.println("IS IN");
      return "index";
   }
}
```

I typed localhost:9000/hello on browser, then browser display this error messages.
HTTP Status 500 - Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'

type Exception report

> message Could not resolve view with name 'index' in servlet with name
>   'DispatcherServlet'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name
>   'index' in servlet with name 'DispatcherServlet'
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1190)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.50 logs.

index.html is located on /webapp/WEB-INF/view/

What I to do Configure anymore?

Comment: Maybe on helloWorld() you need to return "index.html" (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105048/spring-with-thymeleaf-view-integration )

Comment: `localhost:9000/hello` are you missing context name (project name ) in url ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the javadoc of [`ThymeleafViewResolver#setViewNames(String[])`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring3/2.1.2.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring3/view/ThymeleafViewResolver.html#setViewNames%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). It states

> Specify a set of name patterns that will applied to determine whether
>   a view name returned by a controller will be resolved by this resolver
>   or not.

The view name your `@Controller` handler method returns is

```
return "index";
```

That view name definitely does not match the pattern

```
*.html
```

You would have to use

```
return "index.html";
```

for Spring to use your `ThymeleafViewResolver`, though that would fail at a later step since no such resolved JSP exists.

Instead, just get rid of the `viewNames` `<property>` or fix it and your `@Controller` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

replace the last bean alone in thymeleaf resolver with this code it will work fine

```
<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />

</beans:bean>
```